# Why super class has different id-s of objects in python?

Tags: python, inheritance

Consider such code snippet:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        print(id(self))


class D(C):
    def __init__(self):
        super(D, self).__init__()
        print(id(super(D, self)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    d = D()
```

which produces for me:

```
140267543158096
140267543678800
```

Why this happens?
I expected that result should be the same because super(D, self) and `self` in `C` is the same object.

Comment: Because `super(C, self))` in `D.__init__`  is a *`super` object*, whereas `id(self)`in `C` is a `D` object. They are *two different types of objects*, let alone identical objects. Try printing `type(self)` in `C.__init__` and `type(super(C, self))` in `D.__init__`. You must understand, `super` is a *class*, it returns a special type of object that acts as a *proxy* for a method call, giving you the *next method in the method resolution order*.

Comment: Note, generally, you wouldn't call `super(C, self)` inside a method of `D`. It's possible, but unusual

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I updated the code, but result is the same.

Comment: Please read my *first comment*. The second one was an aside, that isn't relevant to this behavior.